# Active Admin and Devise after sign in redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have ActiveAdmin model created by active admin and User model created by devise.

After login on /users/sign_in the user is redirected to  and after login on `/admin/login` i want the admin user to be redirected to `/admin` instead they are being directed to `/users/sign_in`

Here is my code...

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if admin_user?
    admin_root_path(current_user)
  else
    user_home_path(current_user)
  end
end
```

What could we do to make it work?